# Use python exec safely

Tags: python

I would like to read a set of variable definitions from a file. I would like to use `execfile` to read them (to simplify my input code). Consider:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from math import *
import os

cmd="""
a=[0,3]
b=[0,1]
print 'Hello'
print sin(2)
os.system('rm my_important_file')
"""
gd={}
ld={}
exec(cmd,gd,ld)
print ld
```

(I use here `exec` instead of `execfile` to simplify the question). As you see I am trying to use `exec` safely by supplying dictionaries as second and third argument. I would like to only have variable definitions as valid operations in the input file. So `print 'Hello'`, `print sin(2)`, and `os.system('rm my_important_file')` should all produce errors. It seems to work for the last two, but not for `print 'Hello'`. What is the reason for this?

Comment: `print 'Hello'` works because it only refers to a literal value.

Comment: Strong suspicion of [a XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) here... In other words, there's probably a better solution to the problem you're trying to solve than to `exec` a file.

Comment: If you don't trust the author of the file, then don't execfile it.  You can't make it safe:  http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is a statement, a language feature. No imports are required to execute it. You are executing *all valid Python code* when using `exec` or `execfile`, and that includes the `print` statement.

Your empty dictionaries will also not prevent imports. I can still do:

```
import os
os.system('rm my_important_file')
```

in the config file and have it executed under the privileges of the Python code that called `execfile()` on this file.

If your config file is only allowed to use assignments and a subset of expressions, **don't use `execfile` or `exec`**. There is no way of making those 'safe'; Python is too dynamic a language.

Parse the file yourself into a domain specific language, or use a different pre-existing config file format, such as `ConfigParser`. These won't allow for Python expressions to be executed, however.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Good point about `import os`! I can see your point, I just hoped I could make my input code as simple as possible.